# Geometric Series with exp

Tags: calculus, geometric-series

Find all values of $x$ for which the series converges, and find the sum of the series for those values of $x$.
$$e^{-11x}+e^{-22x}+e^{-33x}+e^{-44x}+e^{-55x}+\cdots$$

I figured that I can rewrite this as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(e^{-11x})^{n}$$

I figured that $r = e^{-11x}$ and $a=1$

I had to solve for $\left | e^{-11x}\right |<1$, so $x>0$

Would the sum be?: $$\frac{e^{-11x}}{1-e^{-11x}}$$

Thanks

Comment: I believe you have correctly calculated the sum. Although I will point out for the heck of it that you can multiply through by $$\frac{e^{11x}}{e^{11x}}$$ to get $$\frac{e^{-11x}}{1-e^{-11x}} \cdot \left(\frac{e^{11x}}{e^{11x}} \right) = \frac{1}{e^{11x}-1}$$

Comment: @graydad, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\exp$ is positive (unless you have a complex variable), you can drop the $|.|$. Then the condition is 
$$
e^{-11x} < 1 
$$
As $\log$ increases, this is equivalent to
$$
-11x < 0 \iff x>0
$$under these conditions, the sum value is what you write.